# What does Islam say about introverts?

Tags: sharia, quran, hadith

I feel that I an introvert. Connecting with people is an effort for me. What does Islam say about introverts?

Comment: Do you have a specific question? What do you want to know?

Comment: @ilm, are you talking about extrovert vs introvert? and which way Islam prefers/encourages?

Comment: I want to know the view from an islamic perspective of introverts and if quran mentions anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

Loneliness, and not being confident when addressing to people, are psychological characteristics. No religion has specifically something to say about this (I guess).

Tip: Check out this book [How to win friends and influence people.](http://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/59208/665883919.pdf)<sub>You can buy this too</sub> and Try reading Qur'an to make yourself feel patient and contented.

**Note:** Some flattering techniques and other techniques described in the book are not allowed in Islam.

May the creator guide us all.

Answer (score 0):

i think for each muslims each other we must silaturahmi.

al hujarat 10 says

> The believers are but brothers, so make settlement between your
>   brothers. And fear Allah that you may receive mercy.

and an nissa 1 says

> O mankind, fear your Lord, who created you from one soul and created
>   from it its mate and dispersed from both of them many men and women.
>   And fear Allah , **through whom you ask one another**, and the wombs.
>   Indeed Allah is ever, over you, an Observer.

as a social creature , we need each other, we need other people, in this case introvert mean , you dont want to meet people, or something, for each muslims we dont have to be  introvert, its ok for some cases there are something that you cant expose for each of us. but still we must silaturahmi with each other as a muslim. so make friends with each other for virtue, and do what quran says about silaturahmi,

Comment: What is silaturahmi?

Comment: How many of the estimated [4200 religions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_religions_and_spiritual_traditions) do you know enough for that statement? I would just remove that phrase altogether.